# Blender topology artifacts from cutting

Tags: modeling, topology, artifacts

I am making a pumpkin (based off the Grant Abitt tutorial) and am getting artifacts from the hole cuts. Ive tried fixing the topology but I'm not very good at it. Can anyone give me advice for how to fix it? The issue is coming from bad quad mesh but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can merge vertices (M > Merge at Center for example), dissolve vertices (X > Dissolve), join vertices with J or with the knife (K)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with quads you will avoid artefacts, something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any silver bullet for this - it's usually a case of playing with your vertices until you get something you're a little happier with. You can merge any that are close together, delete them, move them (double tap G to slide along edge).

As a starting point to eliminate any super close vertices you can tab into edit mode, select all, then go to Mesh>Clean Up>Merge By Distance. This will merge any vertices that are sitting very close to each other after running what I guess were some difference booleans?

For help with this mesh specifically, you'll probably need to share the .blend file.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-y834RbWlqR here's the file if you wanna give it a look